# Placeholder for nz select in ngzorro isn't working

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

Here is the code snippet. The placeholder doesn't appear in the dropdown, is blank before choosing an option.

```
<nz-select
           nzShowSearch=true
            class="preview-dropdown"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
            (ngModelChange)="browserSelection($event)"
            nzAllowClear
            nzPlaceHolder="Choose browser">
            <nz-option *ngFor="let browser of browserOptions" [nzValue]="browser.value" [nzLabel]="browser.name"></nz-option>
        </nz-select>
```

Comment: I think, you can see placeholder if you initialize `selectedValue` with `null`

Comment: @Abhijit nope. didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```html
<nz-select 
    nzSize="large"
    formControlName="category"
    [(ngModel)]="x.category"
    [nzPlaceHolder]="'Select a category'"
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

In html:

```
<nz-select nzPlaceHolder="Select a person" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <nz-option nzLabel="Jack" nzValue="jack"></nz-option>
  <nz-option nzLabel="Lucy" nzValue="lucy"></nz-option>
  <nz-option nzLabel="Tom" nzValue="tom"></nz-option>
</nz-select>
```

In ts:

```
selectedValue = null
```

I tryed to set empty string in value. And then placeholder didn't show.